# Module, helper or something else?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I've got a bunch of whitelist functions that do some complex validation on parameters. If you must know, I have several controllers that accept either:

1. A customer ID

   > e.g. `customer=cus_123412341234`
2. A customer Hash

   > e.g. `customer[first_name]=Floating&customer[last_name]=Rock&...`

Remember, there are several controllers that do this (e.g. a charge can be created at the `charges` endpoint using a `customer` ID or a Hash).

Now I want to know *where* I should place these methods (e.g. `customer_hash_params()`,`customer_string_params()`,..)?

Should I:

1. Place them in the `lib/` folder as a Module
2. Place them in the `helpers/` folder as a Helper
3. Something else..

Would like to know what the best practice is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, a helper placed into `app/helpers` might provide some logic for both, controller and view. It is autoloaded for views and need inclusion within controller. A module or class placed within `lib` folder usually extend some controller or model logic. It is not autoloaded into environment, unless specified within `application.rb`

As you have some validation logic, that suits for `lib` directory, because it is not needed within views. I assume these validations are kind of pre-validations and your models do not have all these validated fields defined. Otherwise it would be a good idea to write some custom validators for your models.

Answer (score 1):

Lib Folder in Rails are always used when we have long methods to support controller or model. So that we can call those methods from various controller.

If that is the requirement , Do go for lib Folder, Make a class. Call those class methods in different controllers and models.